# Javascript how to remove corresponding tablerow element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="item01">
            <td><img id="image01" onclick="removeItem()" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="item02">
            <td><img id="image02" onclick="removeItem()" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When clicked upon one of these images (no buttons) `removeItem()` should remove the entire `<tr>` in which the image is placed.

Is there a simple javascript or jQuery way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can someone explain why this has been voted down? perfectly acceptable question if you ask me!

Comment: @series0ne - Probably because it doesn't show that anything was attempted. At this stage it's a gimmie da codez question.

Comment: @series0ne I had tried something, but I was thinking way too difficult, showing the code would have looked foolish if you look at these simple answers :) But I agree normally I should post my code when asking a question like this

Comment: @Forza - no need to explain the lack of code to me :) I don't agree with this "what have you tried" policy because it implies that you've not tried anything, and sometimes, as you say, it's just not practical to post what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the parent element and `this` in markup return the current element which is clicked.

Try this

**jQuery**

```
function removeItem(elem){
    $(elem).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

**Mark up**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="item01">
            <td><img id="image01" src="test.png" onclick="removeItem(this)" />TES</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="item02">
            <td><img id="image02" src="test.png" onclick="removeItem(this)" />test</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3vT8F/)

Comment: Thank you. Never knew something like .closest exists. I'll learn something more every day :)

Comment: Glad it helped! Keep it up! Cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's simple: http://jsfiddle.net/maximgladkov/abMw3/

```
function removeItem(self) {
     $(self).parents('tr:first').remove();
}
```